# Delphi 5 Use Pos / PosIgnoreCase for whole words only

Tags: delphi, pascal, delphi-5

I know Delphi 5 is really old but I have no other choice for now because my employer doesn't want to change, so I am stuck with old functions etc.

I would like to know if there was a way to get the position of the whole words I am looking for:

I have a list of words (if, then, else, and etc) named KEYWORDS, and for each word in it I have to check in every .pas file if this word contains some uppercase characters.

On my code, I am reading each line, and for each line, I am using this to find if I find any word in the list and if it has some uppercase characters:

```
if(PosIgnoreCase(KEYWORDS[I], S) <> Pos(KEYWORDS[I], S)) //Then the keyword has some uppercases in this line and I must raise an error
```

My problem is that if I use some words that contains the keywords ( for example "MODIFICATION") this will detect the uppercase IF in it and raise an error

I tried using `if(PosIgnoreCase(' ' + KEYWORDS[I] + ' ', S) <> Pos(' ' + KEYWORDS[I] + ' ', S))`
but there may be some parentheses or other characters instead of the spaces so I would like to avoid making a new condition for each character.

Is there a clean way to do it ? I found myself struggling quite often with the lack of functions in Delphi 5

Sorry if my question is somewhat confusing, english is not my first language.

Thank you for your time.

---

**Update (from comments):**

*My list of keywords only contains the reserved keywords on Delphi*

Comment: You need to locate/extract words. You could do it like this: https://www.rejbrand.se/rejbrand/article.asp?ItemIndex=505. This is a problem that has also been discussed in several SO questions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, 
If I understand correctly, this function counts the number of words / separators etc,
I could use it to test on each new word if the word is matching, so it would mean I have to test each char on the original String, then if I find a non-word character, add the word to a list, then at the end of the string, check for each word in the list if it is on my Keywords list, then if it contains some uppercase characters, am I right ?

Comment: It's perhaps worh noting that unlike Pos, PosIgnoreCase is not a standard Delphi function.  Also, regarding "there may be some parentheses or other characters instead of the spaces ..."  So do it the other way around and disegard everyting that isn't an alpha-numeric character (or underscore).

Comment: @P.S.: Yes, that function counts words by iterating the text. You don't want the count, but the exact same loop and logic is what you need. Iterate over the text, and handle each word at a time. Of course, under the hood, `Pos` also iterates over the text (but doesn't care about word boundaries). As noted in the linked article, when you extract words, you can either use a "is letter" test or a "is separator" test. (I'll leave it as an exercise for you to determine which approach is most suitable in this case.)

Comment: @MartynA Thank you for your answer, but I cannot include a "if not a character " in my parameters of Pos and PosIgnoreCase

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I see, I will try this then, thank you !

Comment: You can do this test yourself, e.g. `s[1] in ['a'..'z'', 'A'..'Z', '0'..'9'] then ...`

Comment: @MartynA: That will not work for words/identifiers like `Möbius`, `Vigenère`, ... .

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand If there is a word like 'Möbius' etc, it will not be a problem.
My list of keywords only contains the reserved keywords on Delphi, and if I ever happen to find a word like this, it would be on a string, and I don't need to check for keywords in strings

Comment: Good. But I still wanted to mention it, because it is important in many other scenarios. (And btw: I have Delphi functions named `Möbius` and `Vigenère`!)

Comment: I didn't know you could use accents and special chars elsewhere than on strings, I assumed it would cause errors, thank you for making me realize that !

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand : In delphi 5, I can not create a Delphi function like `function Möbius:boolean;` or Vigenère! I'm very interested. Please an working example. Thank you if else :(

Comment: @moskito-x: IIRC, that possibility was added in Delphi 2009. At least I know for sure that Delphi 2009 and later support this.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand:Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @P.S all word in the list here ? [reserved](http://www.festra.com/eng/ref-reserved.htm). They all must have a space at **front** or the "first" in a line and a space  at **end** or be the last in a line/row